# Delphi Tokyo FMX - Access Violation after selecting date from TDateEdit when using Styles

Tags: delphi, styles, firemonkey

I'm getting access violation when click on selected date from TDateEdit picker when using Styles.

First you have to choose any style from style samples at (DELPHI)/Redist/styles/fmx folder, to TStyleBook component.

then run the program and choose any date from datepicker on Windows

Unit: "untDateTime.pas"

```
unit untDateTime;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes, System.Variants,
  FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Graphics, FMX.Dialogs,
  FMX.DateTimeCtrls, FMX.Styles.Objects, FMX.Ani, FMX.StdCtrls, FMX.Effects,
  FMX.Filter.Effects;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    StyleBook1: TStyleBook;
    DateEdit2: TDateEdit;
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.fmx}

end.
```

Images from design and error :

[image]

Comment: Submit a bug report at Quality Portal

Answer (score 0):

Now in Tokyo NeedStyleLookup actually Free control styled resources. And when you click on Date in the popup TCalendar makes IsOpen := False for popup and popupform kill styled resources for TCalendar - FPopupForm.RemoveObject(Self);

I don't see elegance way to fix this by making custom TDateEdit.
Can offer only one quick solution. I don't know situation for ISO and ANDROID here other units(FMX.PhoneDialer.iOS.pas, FMX.PhoneDialer.iOS.pas). For others you can copy FMX.Pickers.Default.pas in your project and rename it for example FMX.Pickers.DefaultFix.pas

now add this changes:

```
procedure TPopupDateTimePicker.DoDateSelected(Sender: TObject);
begin
  TThread.CreateAnonymousThread(
    procedure
    begin
      TThread.Synchronize(nil,
        procedure
        begin
          IsOpen := False;
        end);
    end).Start;

//  IsOpen := False;
end;

procedure TPopupDateTimePicker.DoDayClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  DoDateChanged(Parent);

  TThread.CreateAnonymousThread(
    procedure
    begin
      TThread.Synchronize(nil,
        procedure
        begin
          IsOpen := False;
        end);
    end).Start;

//  IsOpen := False;
end;
```

and add

```
initialization
{$IFNDEF IOS OR ANDROID}
  UnregisterPickersService;
  RegisterPickersService;
{$ENDIF}
end.
```

Comment: This AV behaviour was happening in the Berlin version too.
I had to disable StyleBook on Windows Version to do not have this problem.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
procedure TMAIN.AppException(Sender: TObject; E: Exception);
begin
  //--- DO NOTHING ---
  //Application.ShowException(E);
  //Application.Terminate;
end;

procedure TMAIN.DateEdit2Change(Sender: TObject);
begin
Application.OnException := AppException;
end;
```